# Facebook Graph Explorer Error Code 100 (OAuthException)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-c#-sdk

So I am inputting my correct access token and the correct ID, and when I use GET, it returns this error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Requires user session", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

When I use Get Access Token to get a test token, it returns the correct information. Why is this happening?

Comment: It say the access token needs to be a user access token. I'm guessing you are not using a user access token

Comment: Could be. Where would I find the user access token at then? Would it be in the post with test token that displays the correct information (and not the error?)

Comment: You get the user access token when the user logs in to your app

Comment: So I put in my App ID and App secret, then I try with a different ID and it works fine, but the other one is broke. Would that be because the App Secret/ID is wrong, or the ID (the # in the GET box) is wrong? Sorry, I'm fairly new to the FB world